# How to localize crystal report legends label text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report chart and want to localize all its label texts to support multiculture
software. I can edit label text using "Edit Axis label" option. But how I can externalize/localize? If I have to pull key-value from my resource .resx file and remove the hardcoded string?

Answer (score -1):

[Crystal Reports: Strategy to Localize a Report (labels)](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2009/07/09/crystal-reports-strategy-to-localize-a-report-labels/)